# Laravel Filament library magic

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade, laravel-filament

I know Laravel use Facades and Containers that overload class methods, but when I read the documentation of Filament I see a method called by the Filament facade and this method is named "serving". So I decided to make a search with VS Code in all the files on the project to find the keyword "serving" and I'm not excluding the "vendor" folder, but the only thing I can find is the DispatchServingFilamentEvent class. I never find an occurency of the "serving" keyword anywhere.
There is not Trait containing this method in the Filament vendor directory nor using a function from anywhere.
It's just curiosity but I can't figure how it is possible.
Can anyone explain this sorcery to me please ?

It looks like this :
Filament::serving()

https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/appearance#changing-the-brand-logo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a static facade method, it calls this method on the `FilamentManager` class:

https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/blob/2.x/packages/admin/src/FilamentManager.php#L163-L166